# Loading from JAR as an InputStream?

Tags: java, jar, classloader, inputstream

Is there a ClassLoader implementation I can use to load classes from an InputStream?

I'm trying to load a JAR for which I have an InputStream into a new ClassLoader.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is unlikely, as you will find if you try to do it yourself. You won't be able to randomly access an `InputStream` to look up classes as they're requested, so you'll have to cache the contents either in memory or in the file system.

If you cache on disk, just use [URLClassLoader](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html).

If you cache in memory, you'll need to create some sort of `Map` with [JarInputStream](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarInputStream.html) and then extend `ClassLoader` (overriding the appropriate methods). The downside of this approach is that you keep data in RAM unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not really an answer to your question regarding JAR/`InputStream`.
But following may be an alternative solution to what you are trying to achieve.
Here is some code that will add a URL to classpath.

You may convert a `java.io.File` to `URL` as
`f.toURI().toURL()`

```
/**
 * Adds a URL to current classpath.
 * @param url url
 */
public static void addURL(URL u) {      
    URLClassLoader sysloader = (URLClassLoader)ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    try {
        Method method = URLClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod("addURL",parameters);
        method.setAccessible(true);
        method.invoke(sysloader,new Object[]{u});
        System.out.println("Dynamically added " + u.toString() + " to classLoader");
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```