# Loading an external Jar file from an InputStream

Tags: java, classloader, inputstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loading from JAR as an InputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614095/loading-from-jar-as-an-inputstream)

Is it possible for me to load a jar file from an input stream (from a url connection, for example), load it into a classloader, and execute it?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: how about embedding that external jar file within your main jar file

Comment: @NidhinKrishnan Loading classes at runtime is the norm for plugins among other things.

Comment: @Vulcan i mean we can combine an external jar with our main application jar through changing some code in build.xml. for example if we need mysql.jar for our application ,and when we clear and build the application libraries will be kept into a separate lib folder. we can prevent that by changing some code in build.xml and we can combine all libraries within the main jar file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes; [`URLClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) is intended for this purpose.  It can load classes from an array of URLs.

```
URL externalJar = new URL("http://example.com/app.jar");
URL localJar = new URL("C:/Documents/app.jar");
URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(URL[]{ externalJar, localJar });
Class<?> clazz = cl.loadClass("SomeClass"); // you now can load classes
```

If your `InputStream` is not based on a `URL`, you could instead write the stream's contents to a temporary jar file which you then load using the above approach. (You *can* load a jar entirely in memory, meaning no temp file is created, but this method takes considerably more effort to do right, because you will need define a custom ClassLoader).

Comment: I ended up loading the jar all in memory. It took some time, but it better suited what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
   public static URL getJarUrl(final File file) throws IOException {
        return new URL("jar:" + file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm() + "!/");
    }
```

This properly fetches the URL of the of the Lib because Jar files do some wonky stuff when trying to get their URL.